# Add values from Series with n rows, to Dataframe with m>n rows according to column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe **A**:

| index | some_n |
| --- | --- |
| adf1 | xy100 |
| adf2 | xy100 |
| adf8 | xy100 |
| fds6 | xy201 |
| dfg9 | xy202 |
| sds3 | xy202 |

And a Series **b**:

| index | my_value |
| --- | --- |
| xy100 | 0.435 |
| xy101 | 0.846 |
| xy201 | 0.786 |
| xy202 | 0.258 |

Now, I want to create a Dataframe such that **D**:

| index | some_n | my_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adf1 | xy100 | 0.435 |
| adf2 | xy100 | 0.435 |
| adf8 | xy100 | 0.435 |
| fds6 | xy201 | 0.786 |
| dfg9 | xy202 | 0.258 |
| sds3 | xy202 | 0.258 |

I can mostly do it by doing:

```
b.index.set_names('some_n', inplace=True)
D = pd.merge(A, b.rename('my_value'), on='some_n')
```

The problem with this approach is that it removes the index from the **D** dataframe, and I want to keep the dataframe as the one in **A**.

Comment: `A['my_value']=A['some_n'].map(dict(zip(b['index'],b.my_value)))`

Comment: @wwnde if b is a series then you don't need to do the zip and dict.  You can map a pd.series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map:

```
A['my_value'] = A['some_n'].map(b)
```

Comment: I think it's mostly this but it's complaining with: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: To get A are you filter an another dataframe?   use `copy`,  A = df[condition].copy()

Comment: Silly me, you are right, it was something I did to create A.